# WPF multi converter is not called for textchanged command

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

I have a WPF UI that as shown below. It has a combobox that contain all items, each item contains 2 segment.The segment views are placed on a diffferent content control.Each segment view has a checkbox to enable/disable the content of the entire segment.

my binding in segment view

```xml
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Name="leftDistanceTextBox" 
                     Text="{Binding LeftDistance, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DistanceChangedCommand}">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BeamIntersectionMultiConverter}" ConverterParameter="true">
                                    <Binding ElementName="leftDistanceTextBox"/>
                                    <Binding ElementName="enabledCheckBox"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBox>
```

my converter

```
 public class BeamIntersectionParamMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            // it never stops here in debug mode, except the initializtion
            Debugger.Break();
            if (Validate(values, parameter))
            {
                TextBox control = values[0] as TextBox;

                CheckBox activation = values[1] as CheckBox;
                bool isEnabled = activation.IsChecked == true ? true : false;

                string text = (string)parameter;
                bool.TryParse(text, out bool isLeft);

                return new BeamIntersectionParam(control, isEnabled, isLeft);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
```

The problem is that: I want to validate/ update the viewmodel through the interation.Command.
That Command has a MultiBindnig with one Binding to the current text box and the other Binding to the mentioned CheckBox.
However, the parameter passed into the invoked method only has the initial status of the first item in combobox (the content of the TextBox is up to date though).
Later on, I add the Debugger.Break() to my converter in debug mode and found out that the converter was call only once during the initialization of the view.

If my converter was call only once, why do I get the up-to-date content of bound textbox in invoke method?

If it is called everytime, why do the code does not stop inside the converter indebug mode?

What is happening and how to fix it? Thank you all very much.

P/s: I am sorry in advance because English is not my mother tounge. If you need more information, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's because you're binding to the `CheckBox` control itself (which doesn't "change" except when it is loaded on initialization), rather than its `IsChecked` property.

Does something like the following work (Note: You will have to change your converter as it will be receiving a value of type `bool`, as opposed to type `CheckBox`):

```
<Binding ElementName="leftDistanceTextBox"/>
<Binding Path="IsChecked", ElementName="enabledCheckBox" />
<Binding Path="Text", ElementName="leftDistanceTextBox"/>
```

Comment: Well I tried your suggestion but it does not work. Besides, I find it strange because the binding works with TextBox and some other control, and even CheckBox in my other project. You are right about the control itself does not change, but iits content/ value ... does change. Since i bind to the control, I can access to the content/ values... through the control. Or at the very least that is what I thought and have been experienced until now.

Comment: I understand a bit better now, but I'm wondering if the `CommandParameter` is pre-calculated when the control loads. Perhaps you could try adding `<Binding Path="Text", ElementName="leftDistanceTextBox"/>` and see if that changes things. This would have to be an additional binding to the original `TextBox` one, as you need the control to create the actual parameter. I've updated my answer to show what this would look like.

Comment: Well it works the same as before, so I 'd say that instead of binding to the TextBox, I just bind to the "Text Property". However, there are a few thing I want to do with the Control, thus I would rather stick with the original binding so that I can retrieve the TextBox through the parameter converter.

About the command parameter, I believe it is calculated when the command is invoked - a.k.a when the routed "TextChanged event" happened. Any further document/ information about this is much appreciated.

Comment: If your converter is called only once, I think that suggests the parameter is calculated once, unless a binding's value changes. Are you seeing it called again when the command is fired? I was suggesting binding to both the `TextBox` and it's `Text` property, like in my answer, so you could still access the control in the converter. I'm also wondering if you'd need to add `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` in the `Text` binding?